# Changing a default model field name that django class based views look for

Tags: python, django, django-authentication

I am using `PasswordResetView` (the class-based view in Django 2.0) to implement Forgot Password functionality into my app. I am new to class based views and by default it looks for `is_active` in my user model. However, I overrode the default user model and my model instead contains the field with the name `active`. How do I change this behavior?

```
FieldError at /account/reset-Password/
Cannot resolve keyword 'is_active' into field. Choices are: active, admin, confirm, email, full_name, id, last_login, logentry, password, social_auth, staff, timestamp, userlogin, username
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/account/reset-Password/
Django Version: 2.0.5
Exception Type: FieldError
Exception Value:    
Cannot resolve keyword 'is_active' into field. Choices are: active, admin, confirm, email, full_name, id, last_login, logentry, password, social_auth, staff, timestamp, userlogin, username
Exception Location: /home/yash/Desktop/ltigo/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py in names_to_path, line 1379
Python Executable:  /home/yash/Desktop/ltigo/bin/python
Python Version: 3.6.5
Python Path:    
['/home/yash/Desktop/ltigo/src',
 '/home/yash/Desktop/ltigo',
 '/home/yash/Desktop/ltigo/lib/python36.zip',
 '/home/yash/Desktop/ltigo/lib/python3.6',
 '/home/yash/Desktop/ltigo/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/lib/python3.6',
 '/home/yash/Desktop/ltigo/lib/python3.6/site-packages',
 '/snap/pycharm-professional/68/helpers/pycharm_matplotlib_backend']
Server time:    Mon, 16 Jul 2018 15:18:07 +0000
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix that particular error, it looks as if you have to subclass [`PasswordResetForm`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/93e721a0b8155470336357c148c4d8364c36bbee/django/contrib/auth/forms.py#L231) so that it doesn't use `is_active`. Then use your form in your password reset view.

However, I would recommend against renaming the field to `active` - it is likely to cause problems in other places as well.

Comment: Thanks, that was my last option. I'm gonna go with that then.